# grails 3 tomcat war web url context

Tags: tomcat, grails, grails-3.0

Is there a how-to explained for grails 3 app run on/in tomcat 8?

Background: 
| Grails Version: 3.0.9
| Groovy Version: 2.4.5
| JVM Version: 1.8.0_91

`Grails application running at http://localhost:8080 in environment: production
INFO org.springframework.security.core.SpringSecurityCoreVersion - You are running with Spring Security Core 4.0.3.RELEA`

Current steps I'm at now:

1. grails compile
2. grails prod war
3. java -Dgrails.env=prod -jar build/libs/gr-base-0.21.war

This is able to run the app. I'm able

- able to see html directory http://localhost:8080/privacy.html
- redirection to default spring login page (accepts u/p)
- Unsecured json service webapi works fine!

ERROR 1: 
````
ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for
servlet [grailsDispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name '/index' in
servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/index' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'

```
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1227) ~[spring-webmvc-4.1.7.R
```

ELEASE.jar!/:4.1.7.RELEASE]
````

Another error in logs is: 

`ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/].[grailsDispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for
servlet grailsDispatcherServlet threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'`

I tried setting the context in application.groovy: 

`app.name=livecam
grails.app.context = "/livecam"`

The static security settings are thus: 

    `grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    [pattern: '/',               access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/error',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/register',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/failed',          access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index.gsp',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/shutdown',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/assets/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/logout/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/login/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/js/**',       access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/css/**',      access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/images/**',   access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/appstatus/**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/appStatus/**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/stats/**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/stat/**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/hello/**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/index/**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/testing/**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/j_spring_security_logout**', access:['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/j_spring_security_facebook_redirect**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '//j_spring_security_facebook_json**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/j_spring_security_facebook_redirect/**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '//j_spring_security_facebook_check/**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/j_spring_security**', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/*.htm*', access: ['permitAll']],
    [pattern: '/**/favicon.ico', access: ['permitAll']]
    ]`

The static security was an update, I suspect the leading `/**/` needs to be there! :( Let's hope this is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9302

getting the search keywords correct is beneficial.

graemerocher commented on Oct 7, 2015
You can workaround the issue by doing cd build/libs and then java -jar app310-0.1.war

Grails gets confused because it thinks you are running the project locally if you run it from the project root.
keywords that worked were:

`ServletException: Could not resolve view with name '/error' in servlet with name 'grailsDispatcherServlet'`